# Calling a function or the whole file

Tags: python, function

Before I ask the question let us assume the following two python files as listed below. When calling `file2.bar()` in file1.py does it then ONLY call the function `bar` from file2.py or does it also call all the code that is outside the function as in this case being `foo = 'Hi'`?

file1.py

```
import file2

x = file2.bar()
```

file2.py

```
foo = 'Hi'

def bar():
    a = 10
    return a
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  What could you do to tell if `foo = 'Hi'` was executed or not?

Comment: `import` statements always evaluate everything in the imported file. Use `if __name__ == '__main__':` in `file2.py` if you want it to have some code that's not executed upon importing it.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the Python import machinery has to import a file, the whole file is executed, then either a reference to the module (for `import file2`) or references to some symbols (for `from file2 import bar`) are added to the importing module.

If the module is later imported again, only the relevant symbols are locally added but the module body is not executed again.

So, for your direct question, `foo = 'Hi'` will be executed.

Comment: Your are touching upon the center of my question. You say: "if the module is imported again ...." Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `import file2`, all of the code in file2 is executed (with the exception being code contained inside a `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement which does not apply in your case). This includes all variable/function/class definitions.

Calling `file2.bar()` will only call the `bar()` function - it does not re-execute your `foo` definition. However, the `foo` variable does still exist as it was defined when you called `import file2`. You can access `foo` using `file2.foo`.

There is more information on python modules in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be careful of your terminology. `import file2` doesn't *call* anything; it executes the code in file2.py, and thereby creates a namespace `file2`. In particular, when the code is imported, and therefore run, the objects `file2.foo` and `file2.bar` are created^*. The former is equal to `'Hi'` and the latter is the function you `def`ined.

^*along with quite a few objects related to how python stores information, which you don't normally need to worry about